# truncate text and expand text via read more link

Tags: javascript

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

I've written what should be a simple script to truncate text after a certain length, which reveals a link to expand the truncated text.

Everything works except the text revealing and I am not sure why?

I've uploaded the script to JS Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/oc5s62gr/

```
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let intro = new ShowMore('description', 'read_more', 300);
});
function ShowMore(e, l, stop) {
    this.e = document.getElementById(e);
    this.stop = stop;
    this.l = document.getElementById(l);

    this.l.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.expand_text();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    this.get_length = () => {
        return this.e.innerText.length;
    };

    this.hide_text = () => {
      this.e.innerText = this.e.innerText.substr(0, this.stop) + '\u2026';
      this.l.style.display = 'inline';
      this.e.appendChild(this.l);
    }

    this.expand_text = () => {
      this.e.innerText;
    }

    this.show = () => {
        return (this.get_length() > this.stop) ? this.hide_text() : this.expand_text();
    };

    this.show();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expand_text method isn't doing anything, really. You need to keep a reference of your original text and then use that to change it

```
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let intro = new ShowMore('description', 'read_more', 300);
});
function ShowMore(e, l, stop) {
    this.e = document.getElementById(e);
    this.stop = stop;
    this.l = document.getElementById(l);
    // 1. Keep a reference of your original string
    this.originalTxt = this.e.innerText;

    this.l.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.expand_text();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    this.get_length = () => {
        return this.e.innerText.length;
    };

    this.hide_text = () => {
      this.e.innerText = this.e.innerText.substr(0, this.stop) + '\u2026';
      this.l.style.display = 'inline';
      this.e.appendChild(this.l);
    }
    // 2. revert to original text, stored in local variable
    this.expand_text = () => {
      this.e.innerText = this.originalTxt;
    }

    this.show = () => {
    return (this.get_length() > this.stop) ? this.hide_text() : this.expand_text();
    };

    this.show();
};
```

A [fork of your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zpo5n9h/)

Comment: thank you for your speedy response! you are absolutely right, I modified my code with your suggestion and it immediately worked. What a silly error to make on my part. I very much appreciate your input.

Comment: Happens to everybody, all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

The only statement inside the `expand_text`  function is `this.e.innerText;`, which will do nothing.

You should store the original value of the description string before truncating and use it to display the full text

```js
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      let intro = new ShowMore('description', 'read_more', 300);
    });

    function ShowMore(e, l, stop) {
      this.e = document.getElementById(e);
      this.eText = this.e.innerText;
      this.stop = stop;
      this.l = document.getElementById(l);

      this.l.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.expand_text();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });

      this.get_length = () => {
        return this.e.innerText.length;
      };

      this.hide_text = () => {
        this.e.innerText = this.e.innerText.substr(0, this.stop) + '\u2026';
        this.l.style.display = 'inline';
        this.e.appendChild(this.l);
      }

      this.expand_text = () => {
        this.e.innerText = this.eText;
      }

      this.show = () => {
        return (this.get_length() > this.stop) ? this.hide_text() : this.expand_text();
      };

      this.show();
    };
```

```html
  <h1>Show more / less</h1>
  <p id='description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pretium varius dui sit amet
    commodo. Aenean molestie orci vel ante imperdiet vulputate. Mauris ac blandit mauris. Sed varius tellus a dui
    sagittis, et vulputate erat vulputate. Ut at nibh in lorem volutpat viverra eget malesuada enim. Aliquam dictum urna
    porta urna bibendum hendrerit.</p>
  <a style='display: none;' id='read_more' href=''>Read More</a>
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance - you and alou are absolutely correct. I very much appreciate your support and input.